# Convergence of composition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f,g,\varphi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ all measurable functions with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Assume we construct two sequences of functions $f_n, \varphi_n$ **converging** to $f, \varphi$ respectively, and such that $f_n=\varphi_n \circ g$ for all $n$. What type of **convergence** do I need for $f = \varphi \circ g$ to hold? Is pointwise convergence enough?

Comment: If you want the equation to hold at every point you need point-wise convergence of the two sequences.

Comment: Can you give me an intuition of why it's enough?